# Update PHP on Ubuntu from 5.3.2 to 5.3.3

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, upgrade, php, updates

I am trying to upgrade my PHP installation on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS but to no success.

I am trying to upgrade from: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5 with Suhosin-Patch tot PHP 5.3.3

This:

```
sudo apt-get install PHP5-cgi PHP5-cli
```

did not do the job. Any idea's?

Comment: [Fabián Arias backported php 5.3.5](http://blog.leenix.co.uk/2011/06/ubuntu-1004-lts-lucid-php-533-backport.html). Worked like a charm to get past [bug 50670](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50670) on my 10.04 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 5.3.3 is not yet available from the Ubuntu repository (as can be seen [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/php/)), you can download the source and compile manually though. Download the source [here](http://www.php.net/downloads.php#v5).

Comment: one of the first thing you do after installing an Ubuntu server is adding access to other repository such as Universe! Then you can find all the necessary packages. By default, those are hidden because they are viewed as unnecessary or unsecure. Yet many very useful goodies are in there and perfectly secure.

Answer (score 1):

The patch is packaged for Ubuntu as `php5-suhosin`.

Comment: Which is not available from the repo...

Comment: I pulled the package from universe today.  PHP is 5.3.2, but all the security patches get applied.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.3.3 installation or up-gradation on linux machine,from this [site](http://answers-free.blogspot.in/2014/03/php-installation-or-upgradation-on.html)

Commands to proceed the installation -

> copy PHP_5.3.3.tar file on the local machine using WinSCP or share
>   drive
>
> Untar the tar file use below command
>
> tar -xvf PHP_5.3.3.tar
>
> Then copy or move Unzipped/untar Folder in "usr/opt"
>
> cd /usr/opt
>
> cd PHP_5.3.3
>
> ./configure
>
> make
>
> make install
>
> Installation will take 2/3 mint to upgrade or install the services.
>
> once the installation complete kindly check the installation status or
>   PHP status using below command
>
> command : php -v

Answer (score 0):

above did not work I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.zalexblog.com/2011/01/07/installing-php-5-3-3-on-ubuntu-10-04/)

```
sudo aptitude install php5 php5-cli
```